# Perl - Is there a way to display notifications with some textbox?

Tags: perl, libnotify

Here is my problem : I'm trying to make skype more interactive with my gnome desktop environment. So I want to use Perl to do that. Is there a way, using libnotify, to display a textbox (a field I can fill or type in) ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to display textbox in the notification. The only option libnotify provides other than displaying notifications is to add custom action buttons. If you need to pop-up a text box take a look at  `gxmessage` or you can create your own custom notification like widget using a GUI toolkit

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/214/pidgin-conversation-integration/     
Well I think it's definitely possible. I'll have a look at their code. =)

Comment: Yes, it seems it is possible but not using `libnotify` which you mentioned. The link you gave is using `Message Tray` module of gnome-shell [which is different](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-love/2011-December/msg00013.html) from libnotify.

Answer (score 3):

Gnome provides **zenity** to create dialogs from scripts:

```
zenity --entry --text "foo" --entry-text "bar"
```

KDE provides **kdialog**. Older Gnome provided **gdialog**. There is also **xdialog**.

Comment: Okay that was not what I meant. I don't want a big popup on my screen, juste add a textbox in my gnome3 notification ^^   
I did not mentionned that I was using gnome 3, so it's my fault, sorry ^^